# How do I reassign popup's shortcut in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This `manifest.json` works fine.

```
"commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "windows": "Alt+S",
        "mac": "Alt+S",
        "chromeos": "Alt+S",
        "linux": "Alt+S"
      }
    }
  },
```

How do I allow users to reassign shortcuts? I would like to reassign them right from popup. I have created input, which suppose to be filled with a single letter. This letter suppose to replace 'S' in the manifest. How do I save it into manifest or overwrite shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't integrate shortcut changing in your interface, but you can have a button that links to chrome://extensions/configureCommands